# GWT + EJB + MYSQL

Tags: mysql, gwt, ejb

I have got some Question concerning Serialization and persistence.
At First I have got a GWT project with Client code and a Servlet to communicate with
my EJB Project. 
In the EJB project there are some Persistent Entitie Classes with references among each other and beans to manage them.
The Reference may look like this:

```
         Object A
          /     \
    Object B     Object C
                       \
                     Object D
```

Mostly there are 1:n Relationships, which i have to modelling with oneToMany or something like this..
I store them into a MYSQL Database which already work with Strings.
With Strings I haven't got Problems to transfer them from the GWT Client Side over the GWt Servlet to the EJB Bean and then into the Database and the same way back to the Client Side.
But when I try to transfer an own created Class object (POJO?) between GWT Client and EJB, I always get an Serialization Exception. 
Is it because of the GWT Servlet? I read something that you have to use DTo or Value Objects? Is this correct?
or isn't there a easy way to solve this?

Comment: Does your POJO class implement the serialization interface?

Comment: (The normal at Button don't work ..)

at Entity 

public class TestClass implements Serializable{
 
 at Id
 private String name;
 at OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
 private Collection<Test2> tests;
 
 public TestClass(){
  
 }       

getter + Setter

at Entity
public class Test2 implements Serializable{
 
 at Id at GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;
 private String name;
 
 public Test2(){
 }

getter + setter


Should be correct, I think..

Comment: can you provide more details on the serialization exception.(Copy paste stack trace) or something like that

Comment: To clarify my project structur:
Entities + SessionBean:
http://pastebin.com/4zRHMrcA

GWT Servlet:
http://pastebin.com/rSUSymNi

I have got a GWT Client Side where I temporally want to use POJOs from the EJB Project.
Then there is a GWT Servlet, which is there to communicate with my EJB Project.
At least I have got a EJB Project with my Session Beans for managing the Persistence Entities,
which should be able to be transferd to GWT Client Side.

Comment: When I want to test if I could persist this little example, I got the following Exception:

http://pastebin.com/DEYjBrvY

Seems like I couldn`t use Transactionmanagement..
And how can I tell my GWT Project which Persistence Entities I have?

Answer (score 1):

Please see

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes

All classes that conform to the above specification 
or implement com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable can be serialized.

For example:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Row implements IsSerializable
{
    private HashMap _row;

    public Row()
    {
         _row = new HashMap();
    }

    public Row(HashMap row)
    {
        _row = row;
    }

    public Object getCellValue(String columnName)
    {
        return _row.get(columnName);
    }

    public void setCellValue(String columnName, Object value)
    {
        _row.put(columnName, value);
    }

    public HashMap getRow() 
    {
        return _row;
    }
}
```

In the documentation there is also the link below, I've never tried that

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideCustomSerialization